# Equal separation between elements in a div

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a div, 100px wide, and a variable number (from 1 to 6) of elements, 10px wide, inside that div.

How can I equally space them so that:

- if there is 1 element inside, there will be no additional spacing

  if there are from 2 to 6 elements, spacing between each would be 80px (for 2), 35px (for 3), 20px (for 4), etc...

The first item will always be placed at the most left position, without padding, and the last item will always be placed at the most right position, also without padding.

I'm not concerned about IE, so this could be CSS3. Anyways, I am concerned about javascript. I know this would be a 1 liner in JS, but I certainly want to avoid it if possible, so please refrain answering if you're going to post a JS solution.

Regards

Edit:

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wbiFA

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 900px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-basis: auto;
  width: 171px
}
```

Ok, did it :)

Comment: show the code so far.

Comment: Seems a bit too complex for simple CSS. If you wanted 2 items for example to be evenly positioned, or 3, etc. then a display:table could help, otherwise the css solution ( although possible ) will be a bit too much.

Comment: @AlexChar A sample could would be http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wbiFA you'd need to copy/paste the `item` div from 1 to 6 times.

Comment: @PabloRincon Would the display: table hack work with 6? That is the max items I'd have in a container.

Comment: I havent used flexbox as much, but i know it has a justify option which could help you achieve this. take a look: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: display: table-cell; would get you very close, except perhaps for when there is only one item.

Comment: @PabloRincon Ok, check the update I'll do in a moment, I think I'm close

Comment: @PabloRincon thanks for the flex tip, it's done :)

Comment: Hadn't noticed the flex-basis property. very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need CSS3 features like flexible boxes. The following CSS2.1 features are enough:

- `text-align:justify`
- `display: inline-block`
- `::after` pseudo-element

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.container:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 171px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are a couple of pixels of spacing after the last item. Is that a bug in SO's preview?

Comment: @alexandernst That's because of content model. `width` and `height` properties don't include borders by default. Using [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) would fix that.

Comment: +1, I just removed my answer to gave you a upvote.. I didn't quiet understand the OP answer at first, only after your answer I realized what OP wanted.

Comment: @alexandernst Including a not stabilized experimental technology in a CSS2.1 answer may be a bit incoherent :) Just use `.item{box-sizing:border-box}`. Some people prefer `*,*:before,*:after{box-sizing:border-box}`. You may need vendor prefixes to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Using Flexbox i managed a close enough result:

http://codepen.io/coljung/pen/bufmh

```
.container {
   border: 1px solid red;
   width:1000px;
   height:100px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content:  space-around;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
}
```

Now, it doesnt achieve the exact padding you are looking for. In that case you have to do it manually for every single case.